# FXML: "Run after initialized"

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX application that uses FXML alongside a controller class written in Java.  In the Java controller I need to take care not to operate on an FXML `Node` element until it's been initialized (otherwise I'll get a NullPointerException), which isn't guaranteed until the `initialize` method is run.  So I find myself doing this a lot:

The controller is set in the **FXML file** like this:

```
<Pane fx:controller="Controller" ...>
...
</Pane>
```

And then here's the controller in the **Java file**.

```
class Controller{
    @FXML
    Pane aPane;
    int globalValue;

    public void setSomething(int value){
        globalValue = value;
        if(!(aPane == null)){  //possibly null if node not initialized yet
            aPane.someMethod(globalValue)
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize(){
        aPane.someMethod(globalValue) //guaranteed not null at this point
    }


}
```

This works, but it's clunky and repetitive.  I have to create the `globalValue` attribute just in case the `setSomething` method is called before `initialize` has been called, and I have to make sure the operations in my `setSomething` method are identical to the operations in `initialize`.

Surely there's a more elegant way to do this.  I know that JavaFX has the `Platform.runlater(...)` method that guarantees something will be run on the main application thread.  Perhpas there's something like `Platform.runAfterInitialize(...)` that waits until initialization, or runs immediately if initialization already happened?  Or if there's another way to do it I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Are you setting the controller on the `FXMLLoader` from code? If not, there is no way you could possibly call `setSomething(...)` before `initialize()` is called by the `FXMLLoader` anyway. Can you give a bit more context?

Comment: I added some clarification in the quesiton.  I discovered this problem when I was originally creating an `FXMLLoader`, and using the `setController` method.  Now I'm using a `Controller` object in a containing class annotated with `@FXML` to access the controller.  Does this issue not exist when it's done that way?

Comment: See answer. If you use `fx:controller` there is no way to access the controller instance between instantiation and the `@FXML`-annotated fields being injected.

Comment: And see update for handling the `setController(...)` approach.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!  JavaFX is still pretty new to me, so a lot of these little idiosyncrasies and gotchas are still getting me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you specify the controller in the FXML file with `fx:controller="Controller"`, then when you call `FXMLLoader.load(...)`, the `FXMLLoader`:

1. parses the FXML file
2. creates an instance of `Controller` by (effectively) calling its no-arg constructor (or, in advanced usage, by invoking the controller factory if you set one)
3. creates the UI elements corresponding to the elements in the FXML file
4. injects any elements with an `fx:id` into matching fields in the controller instance
5. registers event handlers
6. invokes `initalize()` on the controller instance (if such a method is defined)
7. returns the UI element corresponding to the root of the FXML hierarchy

Only after `load()` completes (i.e. *after* the `@FXML`-annotated fields are injected) can you get a reference to the controller with `loader.getController()`. So it is not possible (aside from doing something extremely unusual in a controller factory implementation) for you to invoke any methods on the controller instance until after the `@FXML`-injected fields are initialized. Your null checks here are redundant.

---

On the other hand, if you use `FXMLLoader.setController(...)` to initialize your controller, in which case you must not use `fx:controller`, you can pass the values to the constructor. Simply avoiding calling a `set` method on the controller before passing the controller to the `FXMLLoader` means you can assume any `@FXML`-annotated fields are initialized in the controller's public methods:

```
class Controller{
    @FXML
    Pane aPane;
    int globalValue;

    public Controller(int globalValue) {
        this.globalValue = globalValue ;
    }

    public Controller() {
        this(0);
    }

    public void setSomething(int value){
        globalValue = value;
        aPane.someMethod(globalValue)
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize(){
        aPane.someMethod(globalValue) //guaranteed not null at this point
    }


}
```

and

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml"));
Controller controller = new Controller(42);
loader.setController(controller);
Node root = loader.load();
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. It is a shame JavaFX has such problems because this makes very hard to work with Scene Builder and passing data to the controller before initialize().