# fxml getTitle method can't be interpreted by FXMLLoader

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, fxmlloader

I have a problem with my FXML code.
I want to get the String of the stage title when I initialize it, but when I try to call the operation `stage.getTitle()` the FXMLLoader throws an exception.
I also tried to get the title within other methods but it worked only in some of them. Can someone tell me what the problem is right there?

This is where the stage is initialized:

```
@FXML
private void handleModellAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("InEX.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) load.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();

    link = (Hyperlink) event.getTarget();
    model = link.getText();

    stage.setTitle(model);
}
```

This is the initialize method in the controller class:

```
public void getTitle(){
    System.out.println(this.stage.getTitle());
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    image = new Image("images/test.png", 1500, 900, true, true);
    interieurImg.setImage(image);

    model = this.stage.getTitle();
}
```

This is the exception that is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)         
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)      
   at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)       
   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)      
   ... 52 more      

   Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: file:/C:/Users/p356545/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VFAfxml3/dist/run1293777989/VFAfxml3.jar!/vfafxml3/Interieur.fxml        
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)        
   at ...       
   at vfafxml3.InEXController.handleInterieurAction(InEXController.java:58)     ... 62 more         

   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException        
   at vfafxml3.InterieurController.getTitle(InterieurController.java:49)        
   at vfafxml3.InterieurController.initialize(InterieurController.java:88)      
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)     ... 70 more
```

Comment: Maybe you are asking for the stage's title too early :) i think if you call that function after the initialization is done it would work. Try it and tell me

Comment: Show where `initialize` method is invoked, please.

Comment: @Calips
I tried it within a simple buttonClicked method and it throws a similar exception. Strangely enough it works in a navigation method invoked by a HyperLink.

Comment: @LazerBanana
I didn't invoke it manualy. I think it happens automaticlally, doesn't it?

Comment: Try to call setTitle before the getTitle tell me what you get

Comment: I think is too early, look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40247181/4664558) from @James_D `FXMLLoader` runs after `initialized`

Comment: @Calips
If i call setTitle befor the getTitle it also throws a exception :/

Comment: @pR4yChaos, try to set the title value in the constructor of the controller or maybe in the fxml from Scene Builder

Comment: @LazerBanana
I think so, too. But why it doesn't work if I try to get it with a simple button?

Comment: maybe you are trying to do a similar thing, depends on how you structure it.

Comment: Try this first in your getTitle method: `Stage stage = (Stage) OneOfYourComponents.getScene().getWindow();
System.out.println(stage.getTitle())`.

Comment: Check this for [`constructor` vs. `initialize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785417/javafx-fxml-controller-constructor-vs-initialize-method)

Comment: @Calips 
This one worked, thank you.
But within the initialize method it is still to early.
I'll define the String with the controller constructor. Thank you :)

Comment: Where do you initialize `stage` in the second controller?

Comment: @pR4yChaos you should write the answer and validate it or should i write the answer ?

Comment: @Calips
You can do it if you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is too early to get the stage title in the initialize-method. You can get it in any other method after the stage is initialized with the following implementation:

```
public String getTitle(){
    Stage stages = (Stage) anyChoosenElement.getScene().getWindow();
    String modelString = stages.getTitle();
    return modelString;
}
```